# Creating a temporary xml file with php

Tags: php, xml, dynamic-data, temporary-files

I am trying to create a temporary xml file with php that contains a list of quiz quesstions. The random list is generated from a database in php and I need to save this as a writable temporary xml file until the quiz is complete. I keep getting the following errors:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: /tmp/quiz7YRGPo:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/dir/public_html/website.com/quiz/index.php on line 154
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: quiz_data.xml in /home/dir/public_html/website.com/quiz/index.php on line 154
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /home/dir/public_html/website.com/quiz/index.php on line 154

This is the code:

```
// name of XMLPHP file which contains quiz data

$xml_file = 'http://website.com/quiz/dynamic_php_page_generates_xml.php?param=var&param2=var2';


// create randomXML file

$tempquiz = tempnam('/tmp','quiz');
$fp_tempquiz = fopen($tempquiz, "w");
fwrite($fp_tempquiz, $xml_file);
//CLOSE temp file
fclose($fp_tempquiz);

// create new SimpleXML object from XML file

$quiz = simplexml_load_file($tempquiz);
```

How do I create the temporary xml file with php so that the quiz is unique each time the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xml_file` contains the URL of your file, not the actual XML content. You should read it first, with the `file_get_contents` function, for example :

```
$xml_content = file_get_contents($xml_file);
fwrite($fp_tempquiz, $xml_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are just writing this to your XML-file:

```
http://website.com/quiz/dynamic_php_page_generates_xml.php?param=var&param2=var2
```

Because `fwrite($fp_tempquiz, $xml_file);`
 does not know that this is a link which you want to load. You need to load the XML data, not the link to it.

Please refer to this post: [XML Parser Error Start Tag Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059873/xml-parser-error-start-tag-expected)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$xml_file = file_get_contents('http://website.com/quiz/dynamic_php_page_generates_xml.php?param=var&param2=var2');
```